# Change the timeout length in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I did a bulk insert with all variable types as `varchar(max)` because every other insert I tried to do (granted, these weren't with bulk insert, but with the IS component of right click on database name, import data) was getting truncation errors.

Now, when I try to convert to the data type I need, I get a timeout expired error saying that the process took too long. I can, however just do a simple

```
alter table X alter column X int
```

type statement that works.

My question is, why does it work fine one way and not the other? How would one change the timeout time of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running the above statement in SSMS? If so, you should be able to set your execution timeout value to 0 (no timeout limit) when you connect to the server. On the Connect to Server window, press the Options button and there is an option for Execution time-out. Make sure it is 0.